# Proving Negative of Standard Normal is Standard Normal

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let X be standard normal random variable $N(1, 0)$ prove that $-X$ is also standard normal.

I think I am stuck on a technicality but here is my attempt:

Let $Y = -X$

P(Y $\leq$ u) = P($-X$ $\leq$ u) = P($X$ > -u) = 1 - P($X$ $\leq$ -u) = 1 - (1 - P($X$ $\leq$ u) = P($X$ $\leq$ u) which proves the result.

However I am not sure if my last step 1 - P($X$ $\leq$ -u) = 1 - (1 - P($X$ $\leq$ u) is justified. 
I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: I already have trouble with the intended justification of the step $\Pr(-X\le u)=\Pr(X\gt u)$ (second equality).  Also, sooner or later, you will need to use the symmetry of the standard normal.

Comment: Sorry I think I fixed that now.

Comment: @user179206 The distribution is symmetric. Thus $P(X \leq -u)=P(X \geq u)$ This is $1-P(X\leq u)$

Comment: @calculus: Is there any difference between "Negative of Standard Normal is Standard Normal" and "The standard normal distribution is symmetric"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that the distribution is symmetric to prove your result.

You can show it is symmetric looking at the density $$\phi(-x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-((-x)^2)}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x^2)}=\phi(x)$$